# Proof Proving that aj=aj−1+aj−2 cannot converge to a finite limit writing question.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was trying [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1916053/edit) problem and was hoping for some feedback as I am not sure if I proved it or not... I am trying to figure out where I went wrong as I feel I didn't run a good argument.

For $\epsilon>0,\exists N:|a_j-a_{j+1}|<\epsilon$ for$j>N$.

$a_j=a_{j-1}+a_{j-2}$

$|a_j|=|a_{N+1}+a_{j-1}+a_{j-2}-a_{N+1}|$    I added zero in a unique way.

$|a_j|\leq|a_{N+1}|+|a_{j-1}+a_{j-2}-a_{N+1}|$  Triangle inequality

$|a_j|\leq|a_{N+1}|+|a_j-a_{N+1}|$  Substitute in $a_j$

for $j>N$, $|a_j-a_{N+1}| < \epsilon$

$|a_j|\leq|a_{N+1}|+\epsilon$

$|a_j|-|a_{N+1}|\leq\epsilon$ Since epsilon can't be negative and we know $|a_j|-|a_{N+1}|<0$, is there a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not arrive at a contradiction. For example, it is true that $|17|-|42|\le 0.001$ even though the left hand side is negative.

Instead, let $\phi$ be the larger solution of $\phi^2=\phi+1$. Show that $\phi>1$. Show by induction that $a_n>c\phi^n$ provided you pick $c>0$ such that $a_1>c\phi$ and $a_2>c\phi^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do believe that we know that $a_j-a_{N+1}$ is less than zero for the reason that the sequence is growing since each term is the sum of the previous two terms... I still don't know if that proves anything though by saying that a negative number is less than epsilon.